# Bootstrap popover not staying attached to button when scrolled/Positioning is wrong

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a scrollable table with buttons that generate popovers. The problem is that it's positioned in the center of the button and not outside of it.

Here's my JSFiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/Br4Zg/999/

I read on the Bootstrap site that when attaching a popover to a btn-group I need to use 
`container: "body"` attribute, but when I used that then it doesn't scroll with the table since it's not relative to the table anymore as seen in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Br4Zg/1000/

Is there a way to get the position correct along with the scrolling functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the button from the button group then the popover shows up in the correct location.

Remove this

```
<div class ="btn-group btn-broup-sm">
```

Comment: Thanks but is there another way without having to delete btn-group. My project has specialized css for btn-group that I need